# Undefined property: PDOStatement::,$id_login,$nama_depan

Tags: php, pdo

Index.php

```
   require_once '../../konfig/conn.php';
   echo $id = $_SESSION['id'];

   $sql = "SELECT * FROM i_user WHERE id_login = $id";
   $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);
   $stmt->execute() . "<br/>";
```

I'm Try to count data from database and it's working

```
   echo "<br>".$stmt->rowCount()." Total Rows";
```

and the result is "1 Total Rows", Please help me to fixed this...

```
    while ($stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)) {
        echo $stmt->id_login;
        echo $stmt->nama_depan;
    }

    return $stmt;
```

and this picture 
[from my database php code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ST0kc.jpg)

Comment: Did you mean `SELECT * FROM i_user WHERE id_login=$id`? Note the space around asterisk. Without it, it will produce errors.

Comment: One more, your table has no column named `nama_depan`.

Comment: Missing the point of prepared statements by embedding variables directly in the sql - it negates the protection offered

Comment: What error(s) you get?

Comment: sorry, i was wrong to send my picture database, and i was prepaired my picture now.

Comment: Undefined property: PDOStatement::$id_login in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 14 and Undefined property: PDOStatement::$nama_depan in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 15 . i get this error

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Perhaps like this?

```
while($rs = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    echo $rs->id_login;
    echo $rs->nama_depan;
}
```

Or, using prepared statement with a bound variable

```
include '../../konfig/conn.php';
$id=$_SESSION['id'];

$sql="SELECT * FROM i_user WHERE id_login=:id";

$stmt=$conn->prepare( $sql );
if( $stmt ){
    $stmt->bindParam(':id',$id);
    $res = $stmt->execute();
    if( $res ){
        while( $rs=$stmt->fetch( PDO::FETCH_LAZY ) ){
            echo $rs->id_login, $rs->nama_depan;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: does'n working too, i was trying few menutes ago Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 13

Comment: change `echo $id=$_SESSION['id'];` simply to `$id=$_SESSION['id'];`

Comment: does'n woring too, i was to try few menutes ago, this the result :Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 13 and Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 17, i change my php code to be this. `$row==$stmt` but still doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You need to assign the result of the fetch to a variable:

```
while($row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_LAZY)){
    echo $row->id_login;
    echo $row->nama_depan;
}
```

Comment: does'n woring too, i was to try few menutes ago, this the result :Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 13 and Undefined variable: row in C:\xampp2\htdocs\iStuds\modul\modul_user\profil.php on line 17, i change my php code to be this. `$row==$stmt` but still doesn't work

Comment: == is a compaison; = is an assignment. You need an assignment, and not the ==